# Does this have a name (metric space related measure of closeness)?

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider a metric space $(M,d)$, and let $D: M \times M \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a measure of similarity on it, so that $D(x,y)$ is large when $x$ and $y$ are close (i.e., $d(x,y)$ is small).

Consider a collection of points $X := \{x_1,\dots,x_n\} \subset M$. Let 
$$
  N_\epsilon(y;X) := | \{ x \in X: D(x,y) > \epsilon \}|
$$
where the RHS is the cardinality of a set. For a set $Y \subset M$, define
$$
  N_\epsilon(Y;X) = \inf_{y \in Y} N_\epsilon(y;X)
$$
Does this quantity look familiar, or is related to a more standard object?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ instead of $D(x,y) > \epsilon$? What's the precise meaning of "$D$ is large when $d$ is small"? Either way, I don't recall seeing this before.

Comment: In what context did this arise?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, the reason I am using $D$ is the way I have arrived at this quantity. You could define things in terms of $d$ as you pointed out, if that helps.

Comment: @dfeuer, it arised in studying the mixing time of of a Markov chain. I want a lower bound on $\sum_{x \in X} D(x,y)$, uniformly over $Y$, and this seemed natural.